# PHP DateTimeZone Transitions seem to be incorrect

Tags: php, datetime, transition, dst

I am currently using DateTime's with PHP and noticed that the transition times in PHP's DateTimeZone object seem to be incorrect. I have only tested this with the "America/Havana" timezone so I am unsure as to whether this is a problem everywhere or not.

A good example of this would be here:

```
var_dump((new DateTimeZone("America/Havana"))->getTransitions());
```

If you "ctrl-f" and look for "2016-03-13" you'll notice that it says the transition occurs at 5:00 AM UTC on March 13th 2016, when it should actually be at 7:00 AM UTC on March 13th 2016.

I have tried fixing this by installing an external TimeZone DB (timezonedb with pecl to be precise) but the problem seems to persist. The reason I need this fixed is because it seems to be messing with my DateTime object and it isn't acting how it's supposed to. F̶o̶r̶ ̶e̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶s̶e̶e̶m̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶ ̶r̶a̶n̶d̶o̶m̶ ̶h̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶t̶r̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶s̶t̶r̶u̶c̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶p̶e̶c̶i̶f̶i̶c̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶e̶:

```
$̶t̶e̶s̶t̶ ̶=̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶D̶a̶t̶e̶T̶i̶m̶e̶(̶"̶2̶0̶1̶3̶-̶0̶3̶-̶1̶3̶ ̶0̶0̶:̶3̶0̶:̶0̶0̶"̶,̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶D̶a̶t̶e̶T̶i̶m̶e̶Z̶o̶n̶e̶(̶"̶A̶m̶e̶r̶i̶c̶a̶/̶H̶a̶v̶a̶n̶a̶"̶)̶)̶;̶ ̶ ̶
```

I̶f̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶v̶a̶r̶_̶d̶u̶m̶p̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶b̶o̶v̶e̶ ̶v̶a̶r̶i̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶h̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶c̶h̶ ̶m̶a̶k̶e̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶s̶e̶n̶s̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶o̶p̶i̶n̶i̶o̶n̶.̶ Anyways if anyone could help that would be incredible.

**UPDATE**

I haven't solved the issue yet but I seem to have been wrong about one of the examples above. The problem now seems to be that

```
$test = new DateTime("2013-03-13 00:30:00", new DateTimeZone("America/Havana"));
var_dump($test->getOffset());
```

Seems to be returning -14400 because it thinks DST has occurred when in actuality it should return -18000 because DST did not occur yet.

Comment: Could your problem be caused by daylight saving time?

Comment: The problem is my PHP TimeZone DB doesn't seem to contain the proper transition dates as mentioned above. It seems to be 2 hours off and that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = new DateTime("2013-03-13 00:30:00", new DateTimeZone("America/Havana"));
```

**outcome:**

```
public 'date' => string '2013-03-13 00:30:00.000000' (length=26)
public 'timezone_type' => int 3
public 'timezone' => string 'America/Havana' (length=14)
```

It did not added an hour.

What are you trying to achieve? More information would be helpful to get you better answer.

Looking at your example seems like you trying to convert date time to some specified timezone. If that's what your goal is I would highly suggest [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/)

Comment: You're right it does seem to create the DateTime object correctly. I must have done something incorrectly or something when testing it out last time. To update my problem now I would have to say that if you use $test->getOffset() the offset will be incorrect and I use it for a specific purpose. In this case it'll return -14400 when it should still be returning -18000.